# Binary search with "midpoint" at one third

Tags: c++, algorithm, binary-search

Instead of comparing with the midpoint, I want to design a binary search algorithm that compares the item you are looking for with one at the 33th percentile and the 66th percentile using recursion.

This is what I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
//binary search recursion


int binarysearch(int begin, int end, int a[], int key);


void main()
{
    const int size= 10;

    int a[size] = { 22,32,45,55,65,75,90,100 };

    cout<<binarysearch(0, 7,a, 90);
}


int binarysearch(int begin,int end,int a[],int key)
{
    int b = begin+(end-begin) * (1.0/3.0);
    int c = begin +( end-begin)*(2.0 / 3.0);

    if (begin > end)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    if (a[b] == key)
    {
        cout << "b is the key";
        return b;
    }
    if (a[c] == key)
    {
        cout << "c is the key";
        return c;
    }

    if (a[begin] < key&&a[b]>key)
    {
        return binarysearch(begin, b-1, a, key);
    }

    if (a[b ] < key&&a[c ]>key)
    {
        return binarysearch(b + 1, c - 1, a, key);
    }

    if (a[c ] < key&&a[end]>key)
    {
        return binarysearch(c + 1, end, a, key);
    }

}
```

Is this right? Any suggestions?

Comment: Um, the 1/3 point between `begin` and `end` is `begin + (end - begin) * (1.0 / 3.0)`, not `(begin + end) * (1.0 / 3.0)`. (You can write it as `(2.0 * begin + end) / 3.0`.) Similarly for the 2/3 point: use `(begin + 2.0 * end) / 3.0`.

Comment: pretty sure either method works if begin=0 and end =9 then 9/3=3 and18/3=6

Comment: @lolsharp but doesn't works for begin=6 and end=9

Comment: Your method won't work whenever `begin` is anything but 0. It may start out as 0, but after 2 of the 3 possibilities for the first recursion, it won't be.

Comment: ok I think I see it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your recursion logic is still off. You don't need the `begin2` and `end2` arguments; they just add clutter and serve no useful purpose. Your logic should go like this:

1. Find `b` and `c`, the 1/3 and 2/3 intervals. (You're now doing that correctly).
2. If `a[b]` or `a[c]` equals `key`, then you've found the result. (You're also doing that correctly).
3. Otherwise, decide which of the three intervals `key` might be in. The three possibilities are [`begin`, `b-1`], [`b+1`, `c-1`], and [`c+1`, `end`]. Recurse accordingly. (This is the part that you are not doing correctly.)

You should also add one more piece of logic: if `begin > end`, then the key is not in `a` at all.

I'm not going to get any more specific than this, because this sounds like an assignment and you should be writing your own code.

Comment: Hey I think I have the correct code now at least I hope. Although without you I don't think I would have came to this solution. I am an undergrad compsci student this is my first data structures course and I really want to know how do I get to the point where I'm as good as you?

Comment: @lolsharp - The main thing with coding is to break down problems into manageable chunks. Test your assumptions (like you should have done with your first attempt at computing the 1/3 and 2/3 divisions). If something isn't working as expected, don't try something new until you have a reasonable hypothesis about what's actually going wrong. Learn to use debugging tools. And, as the New York native told a tourist when asked how he could get to Carnegie Hall, "Practice, practice, practice". Good luck with your studies!